# How to handle if user stopped after typing in edittext android?

Tags: android, android-layout, chat, android-keypad, android-touch-event

I am developing an app for chat. I can get event to update typing status when user typed or when user erased fully, I can update as "not typing status" and showing as online. Till this process works fine.

But problem is when user typed some lines and stopped, I should not show typing which is applied in whatsapp. How to handle this?

Here is code what i done is.

```
        ChatMsg.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                    int before, int count) {
                   if (edtChatMsg.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0) {
                    if (!isTyping) {
                            isTyping = true;
                            serviceCall();
                          }
                  else{
                      isTyping = false;
                        serviceCall();
                      }
            }
        so at result
    @Override
     protected void onTyping(String message) {
    if (message.equalsIgnoreCase("Typing…")) {
        txtUserPersonStatus.setText("Typing…");
    } else {
        txtUserPersonStatus.setText("Online");
    }
}
```

My question is how to handle when user typed in keyboard for a while and then stop.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically you need to implement some sort of timeout. Every time the user types something, you have to schedule a timeout and reset any timeouts you have scheduled before. Thus when the user stops typing the timer gets triggered after the specified time.

You can do this with a [`Handler`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) for example:

```
final int TYPING_TIMEOUT = 5000; // 5 seconds timeout
final Handler timeoutHandler = new Handler();
final Runnable typingTimeout = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        isTyping = false;
        serviceCall();
    }
};

ChatMsg.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        // reset the timeout
        timeoutHandler.removeCallbacks(typingTimeout);

        if (edtChatMsg.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0) {
            // schedule the timeout
            timeoutHandler.postDelayed(typingTimeout, TYPING_TIMEOUT);

            if (!isTyping) {
                isTyping = true;
                serviceCall();
            }
        }
        else {
            isTyping = false;
            serviceCall();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: perfect one for now :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a Handler :

```
_AFKHandler = new Handler();
_AFKRunnable = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                isTyping = false;
                        serviceCall();
            }
        };

ChatMsg.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                    int before, int count) {
                   _AFKHandler.removeCallbacks(_AFKRunnable);
                   if (edtChatMsg.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0) {
                    if (!isTyping) {
                            isTyping = true;
                            serviceCall();
                            _AFKHandler.postDelayed(_AFKRunnable,AFK_TIMEOUT_VALUE_IN_MS);
                          }
                  else{
                      isTyping = false;
                        serviceCall();
                      }
            }
        so at result
    @Override
     protected void onTyping(String message) {
    if (message.equalsIgnoreCase("Typing…")) {
        txtUserPersonStatus.setText("Typing…");
    } else {
        txtUserPersonStatus.setText("Online");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need use:

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
    //  arg0=null ,Handler ---is empty ;

}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
        int arg3) {
    // Handler --- is typing


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this style , use coundown timer for 500ms. In my view this is the simplest way to solve this problem.Try it an let me know you sugessions

```
lateinit var textFinishTimer: CountDownTimer
EditText.doAfterTextChanged {
    if (this::textFinishTimer.isInitialized) {
        textFinishTimer.cancel()
    }
    textFinishTimer =
        object : CountDownTimer(500, 100) {
                override fun onTick(p0: Long) {}
                override fun onFinish() {
                    if (oldKeyword == it.toString()) {
                        return
                    }else{
                        //Your logic comes here
                    }
                }
            }
            .start()
}
```